# Free groups and free product of groups are isomorphic

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, free-product

I saw the following conclusion from a reference book:

Let $G=*_{i\in I}G_i$ be free product of $G_i$, where each $G_i$ is a group.

If $I=\{1,\cdots, n\}$, each $G_i=\Bbb Z$, then $G$ is isomorphic to the free group $F_n$.

My question is : since each element in $G$ is not uniquely expressed by elements of $G_i$, how to constfuct the explicit bijective map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$$\newcommand{\Span}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}$Use the universal properties. Let $G_{i} = \Span{g_{i}}$ be infinite cyclic, and let $F_{n}$ be the free group on the symbols $h_{i}$.

By the universal property of the free groups, there is a unique homomorphism $\phi : F_{n} \to G$ such that $\phi(h_{i}) = g_{i}$ for all $i$.

The maps $\psi_{i} : G_{i} \to  F_{n}$ given by $\psi(g_{i}^{k}) = h_{i}^{k}$ are clearly group homomorphisms, as $G_{i}$ is infinite cyclic. By the universal property of free products, there is a unique homomorphism $\psi : *_{i} G_{i} \to F_{n}$ such that $\psi(g_{i}) = h_{i}$ for each $i$.

Now $\phi$ and $\psi$ are inverse to each other.

Comment: I have a question: Let $S=\{h_1,\cdots,h_n\}$, if we use the universality of free group, we need to find a group homomorphism from $S$ go $G$,  how to define the group homomorphism fromm $S$ to $G$?

Comment: @mathbeginner, sorry, I do not understand, isn't $S$ just a set?

Comment: Sorry , I mean "a homomorphism from S to G" ,how to define this homomorphism?

Comment: To emphasize the comment of @AndreasCaranti, the set $S = \{h_1,...,h_n\}$ is not a group, so it makes no sense to speak about a homomorphism from the set $S$ to the group $G$, because the domain of a homomorphism must be a group and $S$ is not a group. Fortunately, when applying the universality condition, all you are asked to do is to first provide a function (not a homomorphism) from $S = \{h_1,....,h_n\}$ to $G$, and that function is defined by $h_i \mapsto g_i$; you then get a unique homomorphism $F_n \to G$ whose restriction to the subset $S$ is the given function $h_i \mapsto g_i$.